# Sememe and semanteme

Tags: terminology, semantics

I'm not sure I understand what is the relationship between *sememes* and *semantemes*.

I have the following definitions :

> A *sememe* is a semantic content of a lexeme.
>
> A *semanteme* is a unit which together with *morph* constitutes a morpheme.

Does this mean that a sememe is basically the meaning of a word, and a semanteme is the meaning of a morpheme?

Comment: This is specialized terminology that is only in use in some theories of meaning (or possibly only one -- theorists do make up their own terminology and define it the way they want, using other terms from the same source.) Don't worry about definitions until you have examples. And don't worry about relationships and distinctions between terms until you recognize it in the examples. Data is important; terminology isn't.

Answer (score -3):

Chek this source https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.thoughtco.com/sememe-word-meanings-1691940&sa=D&source=docs&ust=1690203708088134&usg=AOvVaw16BcPdfDa1RT8GnUbgfNbY
It really set my mind free in regards to the above definitions and also abour the definition of SEME.

Comment: This is currently a link-only answer that will probably be deleted. The link is also in a bad shape, containing an unnecessary redirect via google.com. Please repair the link and tell the reader of the answer the main points of the target page. Note the links may go stale at any time without further announce: Be self-contained in the answer.